# How to install and start googlepinyin on debian 10?

Tags: debian

I used debian 10, I have installed "fcitx-googlepinyin_0.1.6-4_amd64.deb" by these: sudo dpkg -f fcitx-googlepinyin_0.1.6-4_amd64.deb

While, I don't know how to and where to start it on GUI.

I guessed maybe it was because that I haven't installed fcitx, so I went to install "fcitx_4.2.9.6-5_all.deb", while in CLI, I saw these:

dpkg:dependency problems prevent configration of fcitx:

It was said, "fcitx-bin", "fcitx-data" and "fcitx-modules" haven't been installed.

When I dowaloaded the 3 files, I found each of them need other dependency, and their dependency are also has dependency, so I think this maybe the solution.

Did anyone here has installed googlepinyin on debian and used it?

When I typed:
sudo apt-get install -f fcitx-bin

It was said:
Unable to locate package fcitx-bin

So, if there is a independent solution for install googlepinyin on debian 10 ?

Below is a screensnap:
[unable to locate package fcitx-bin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKvhc.jpg)

When I want to remove the package by typing these:
sudo apt-get remove tcitx

It was said:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
fcitx:

googlepinyin:

and the three packages:fcitx, googleyinpin and fcitx-bin are shown alternately.

Below is the screensnap:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zt6Yo.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource. However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest solution attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Answer (score 0):

Try using: `sudo apt --fix-broken install` before proceed some other installation.

You can also search your package using: `sudo apt search [packagename]`.
In your case would be: `sudo apt search fctix`.

After all done, install the package using: `sudo apt-get install [packagename]`.

When you get to install, it will appear which new libraries will be added or upgraded.